# How to use LiveData within a pure Java module in Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-architecture-components

I tried to use LiveData within  a pure Java module. I added the dependency in the module gradle file, but Android studio could not resolve the dependency. Saying LiveData is not resolved. Does it only work in Android modules? Or did I miss something?

Comment: "Does it only work in Android modules?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: Did you find a way to get it working in a Java module?

Comment: Unfortunately No!. I converted my Java module into Android Library module to get it word

Comment: @CommonsWare do you now where i can find info saying that shoudn't work outside android module ?

Comment: @cesarsicas: `LiveData` needs to know about the main application thread, so it will need access to Android framework classes like `Looper`. That will not be in an ordinary Java module.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have one Android project who having a java module(like a library).
The problem is that, you are facing problem to user LiveData in java library.
You java library may return some result to the Android project and then you are using it. Is this possible for you to receive response in Android project and after having that response or model whatever it is, put it in a LiveData object of the same response type.